# "lambdas can't have assignment statements" - so why is "foo = lambda x: x * 2" legal?

Tags: python, lambda, variable-assignment

I am reading Functional Python Programming by Steven Lott, a book about using Python 'functionally' instead of in a more object oriented fashion and which focuses on exploratory data analysis for most of its examples.

Lott says that Lamda's can't have assignment statements. But on the same page he assigned a lambda function to a variable:

```
>>mersenne = lambda x: 2**x-1
>>mersenne(17)
 131071
```

How is that not an assignment statement? Is there some other sense of 'assignment' that I am missing?

Comment: Means *lambdas can't contain/enclose assignment statements*

Comment: Assignment to a lambda is like a one line `def` for a function

Comment: You're assigning the lambda itself to a name; in your example, the assignment is *outside* the lambda's definition, not inside it.

Comment: BTW, your original title was much, much broader than your question actually is. I've tried to update it to fit the question in scope -- there are a great many questions and answers about assignments in the context of functional programming [particularly when one brings variants on FP that perform constraint-solving or the like into play] that aren't actually within the range of what you're asking here.

Comment: Thanks, Charles, your title is much clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have assignments inside the "lambda" function, but the lambda itself can be used in assignments.

So you can't say something like `lambda x: y = x*2; return y`, but you can say `foo = lambda x: x*2`

Answer (score 0):

It's not not an assignment.

A lambda in Python cannot *contain* an assignment. But this is pretty much the only aspect of Python which enforces a functional paradigm. The rest of the language has some unescapable procedural features; it is hard to imagine a Python program which didn't contain *any* assignments.

Comment: Thanks. That helps me understand.